# Java dom: getElementsByTagName()'s childNodes having null values

Tags: java, dom, w3c

I am seeing a weird behaviour of w3c dom library for Java. For my XML which is formatted, I ran document.getElementsByTagName().getItem(0).getChildNodes() for fetching one of the tags' child nodes. Below is how my tag looks like:

```
<References>
    <Reference Name="a" Value="1"/>
    <Reference Name="b" Value="2"/>
    <Reference Name="c" Value="3"/>
    <Reference Name="d" Value="4"/>
    <Reference Name="e" Value="5"/>
    <Reference Name="f" Value="6"/>
    <Reference Name="g" Value="7"/>
    <Reference Name="h" Value="8"/>
    <Reference Name="i" Value="9"/>
    <Reference Name="j" Value="10"/>
    <Reference Name="k" Value="11"/>
    <Reference Name="l" Value="12"/>
</References>
```

Below is my code:

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("References").item(0).getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    NamedNodeMap currentItemAttributes = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes();
    String currentItemName = currentItemAttributes.getNamedItem("Name").getNodeValue();
    name=currentItemName;
}
```

Here, I get null value for every alternate node as explained below:

`nodeList.item(0).getAttributes()` returns `null`

`nodeList.item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Name").getNodeValue()` returns `a`

`nodeList.item(2).getAttributes()` returns `null`

`nodeList.item(3).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Name").getNodeValue()` returns `b`

and so on.

Interestingly, if I minify my xml file to a single line and remove all the extra spaces, it works fine and I do not get alternate `null` values.

If anyone can give me a solution to this, it'd be a great help.

Comment: The  whitespace in your file creates extra nodes ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the getChildNodes() is getting all the NODES.

Try

```
document.getElementsByTagName("References").item(0).getElementsByTagName("Reference");
```

Or you can check each node for type (Element) and name (Reference) and handle it then.